# Filter Date Range in Datagridview didn't work if months are different

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datagridview

I know this is an old problem but I still confuse a little bit, please show me how.

I loaded a datatable with conditions in datagridview like the code below, thing is, It worked well when `FromDate` and `ToDate` are the SAME MONTH. Different month makes the datagridview empty.

`FromDate` and `ToDate` are selected in calendar into the 2 textbox.

```
private void LoadWorkRequestSearch()
{
    DateTime datefrom = Convert.ToDateTime(textdatefrom.Text.Trim());
    DateTime dateto = Convert.ToDateTime(textdateto.Text.Trim());

    string sql = "";
    sql = "Select DateCreated, ri.RequestID, RequesterID, RequestStatus, RequestDetail, SentTo, EstimateCompleteDate, ru.StartedDate, ru.ProcessTime From [RequestInfo] ri ";
    sql = sql + " LEFT JOIN [StatusRequest] sr ON sr.RequestStatusID = ri.Status";
    sql = sql + " LEFT JOIN [RequestUsers] ru ON ru.RequestID = ri.RequestID ";
    sql = sql + " Where DateCreated between '" + datefrom.ToShortDateString() + "' and '" + dateto.ToShortDateString() + "'";

    _dtworkrequestsearch = _cls_DB.QueryDataTable(sql);
    G1.DataSource = _dtworkrequestsearch;

}
```

I tried everything I searched but it didn't work the way I want, please help.

Thank you,

Comment: What are the values of `textdatafrom.Text` and `testdateto.Text`? Your code sample does not give us anything to reproduce the problem. Please use hard-coded strings in this case, so we can see what the values are. Is it possible that the date format you're entering is different than the one expected? i.e. `dd/mm/yyyy` instead of `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: Is **DateCreated** table column a date datatype?

Comment: @RufusL yeah, the format of `textdate` is `dd/MM/yyyy` fit exactly in my local database

Comment: @JeremyThompson `DateCreate` is a datecolumn, in sql datatype is varchar(10)

Answer (score 1):

Use a Calendar Control and enforce a date format.

The conversion to date from TextBox is the likely problem, eg dd/MM into MM/dd

**Edit:**

You're using a varchar(10) field for dates. That doesn't allow SQL BETWEENS because it's a text field not numeric/date based, so it performs an alphanumeric search.

Use a SmallDateTime column for DateCreated to get the desired results.

Comment: no no, the calendar control is already used for both textbox, that not the problem. :(

Comment: is the `smalldatetime` including time in this? or just date?
and as i research, is the format of `smalldatetime` is `yyyy/MM/dd`?

Comment: It's supports both date and time. Why it's called small datetime is because it only goes back 1900-01-01 through 2079-06-06. Standard datetime goes back to 1753 when they did a merge with the Gregorian Calendar. See Wikipedia and it goes till 31/12/9999.

Comment: aw just because my date is only date not time, is that ok to use `smalldatetime` ?

Comment: Yes, this is best practice. All time components will be 12:00

Comment: Actually a `date` might be best fit... Just anything but varchar will work. Good luck!

Comment: hey err i dont wanna to put a comment here for long conversation, can you chat with me please?

Comment: @Serenade sure let's start a quick chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146381/discussion-between-serenade-and-jeremy-thompson).